# Raspberry Pi, can't apt-get update [Mirror/DNS]

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ethernet, apt-get

I bought a Raspberry Pi yesterday and I am facing quite a large problem. I can't sudo apt-get update. I think this error comes from my dns because I am connected via ethernet (Physically). so the message it prints when I execute the command is that:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://goddess-gate.com/archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'goddess-gate.com'
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease              
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Reading package lists... Done             
W: Failed to fetch http://goddess-gate.com/archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'goddess-gate.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So to resolve this problem I have tried a few things:

```
- Changing the etc/apt/sources.list to a valid mirror of my country (france)
- Reinstalling Raspbian (1st try was with NOOBS) and now I installed Raspbian with the .img file
- Changing my /ect/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces nameservers to   these ip 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Nothing worked... I am really stucked, there is something elese, I can't browse any website with Chromium but I have internet connexion because I can pip install python modules... here is the Chromium message:
'This site can't be reached' ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Other things, my inet ip is not valid, usally it should start with 192.168 but here it is 168.254.241.6 ... here is my if config:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
enxb827ebaf69fc: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.241.6  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::5d8b:1a8c:c520:c339  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:af:69:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 995  bytes 61042 (59.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 806  bytes 77318 (75.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 806  bytes 77318 (75.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:fa:3c:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Oh and another thing: my inet ip is very strange, it doesn't starts with 192.168 but it is 169.254.241.6, and I can't connect to ssh via this inet adress (My SSH is activated tho)

Answer (score 3):

Type following at the command line in order to edit `resolv.conf` which is the linux configuration file where **domain-name to IP mapping** is stored for the purpose of **DNS resolution**.

```sh
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

then add these 2 lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

hope it will help ...

Comment: Your answer seems OK. Please add some explanation and make advantage from formatting. I edited exemplary for you. Maybe also links can help to read more about: [Setup DNS Resolution With “resolv.conf” in Examples](https://www.shellhacks.com/setup-dns-resolution-resolvconf-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The ip-adress range 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 is used by zeroconf.
Probably there is no active DHCP server in the LAN. Mostly the router is also a DHCP server.
You also have no public IPv6 address. But this could also come from a IPv4 only internet connection.
Try to configure the interface completly manual with corrected ip-address. When there should be an active DHCP server, try to fix it. Sometimes a reboot helps.
You can show your gateway with "ip r". It should be the address of the router.

Important is that the ip-address of the Pi is in the same subnet as the gateway.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I connected Raspberry Pi Directly with an Ethernet Cable.

it work.